# My prefix rids sinning, my suffix is swimming

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

I thought of this riddle with my sister. Feedback is appreciated.

> My prefix rids sinning.
>
> My suffix is swimming.
>
> My infix is cheeky.
>
> And where I live its weedy.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might be

> An **angelfish**

> My prefix rids sinning

> Angel

> My suffix is swimming

> Fish

> My infix is cheeky

> Elf

> Where I live it's weedy

> Angelfish like to live among underwater weeds, that provide them with camouflage

Comment: Great job, spot on! Even the infix part is correct :D